# How do I test a fork of a gem locally?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want to make some modifications to the gem `https://github.com/opscode/knife-ec2` and use that locally with `knife`. I have the `knife-ec2` gem installed locally, but I want to use the modified version for testing purposes. How can I do that?

Comment: Neither linked questions are duplicates. The first one asks for just installing a local .gem file, which results in an awkward process requiring compiling and updating the gem anytime a change is made. Installing from a github repository meanwhile require committing and pushing every single change to the repository. The correct answer would be to use ```gem :foo, path: './path/to/local/checkout/to/foo``` in a Gemfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the path of the gem in your gemfile :

```
gem :foo, :git => 'git://github.com/rails/foo.git'
```